# Int input type in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a textbox that allows only integers. I recently created a page in MVC 3 that has a similar textbox with this input type:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Minute,new {style="width: 250px", @type = "number" })
```

And now I tried to recreate the textbox in MVC 5, but this input type
doesn't seem to work. I don't want to make it in javascrip, or jquery or in C# code. Is there any syntax for it in MVC 5?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "validation." `number` is an input type, which restricts the type of input that can be entered (assuming the user's browser supports HTML5).

Comment: is there any reason you have added ** before @type, can you try to remoe it and check

Comment: @KD I tried to bold it. Didin't work, I'll remove it.

Comment: @TiesonT. Ok. I'll edit it.

Comment: what do you mean by validation? do you just need that the HTML5 number control should render like this? or there is any other behavior you are expecting. you can also add restriction to it using min and max attributes

Comment: @KD This is what I want: the user shouldn't be allowed to input letters. The max and min doesn't really help me

Comment: your model property if allows only int then that should be enough to restrict user from inputting anything other than int

Comment: If your class property "sessionDurationMinutes" is number, then can you try to make it like @Html.EditorFor(model => model.sessionDurationMinutes) and check

Comment: @KD   Lets put it this way: in model it is string. In MVC 3, no problem at all with this input type from the view. And apparently in MVC 5, won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MVC 5.1 or higher , try to make it like following and check if it works

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Minute,new {style="width: 250px", type = "number" })
```

remove the `@` and try

Comment: can you make sure your browser supports HTML 5 controls?  can you see it on this page? http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_number

Comment: that was the problem. I was running it on Internet Explorer , and on Chrome worked like charm. But what happens if I run it on IE?

Comment: you have to check which version of IE you are using. and make sure the version you are using supports HTM5 inputs. check this site for more information http://caniuse.com/. I hope you got answer for your query.

Answer (score 1):

Do not make hard code in html helper,

Just Open your Model and go to that property and use DataAnnotation Class Features.

```
{
    [DataType(DataType.Number)]
    public int? sessionDurationMinutes { get; set; }
}
```

Your Textbox will be reduced to...

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.sessionDurationMinutes, new {style="width: 250px"})
```